# Scala zip arbitrary number of arrays together

Tags: arrays, scala

I'm trying to zip array of arbitrary length in Scala into a single array.

```
val someArray = Array(Array(1,2,3), Array(4,5,6), Array(7,8,9))

 // expected result
Array(Array(1,4,7), Array(2,5,8), Array(3,6,9))
```

The outer array length may vary, whereas the inner array length will be the same. the end ouput can be 
in any form arrays, lists or tuples
Is there any scala function to achieve this? or how would you get this output?
Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Shortest answer I ever wrote on StackOverflow:

```
someArray.transpose
```

Link to [docs](https://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/scala/Array.html#transpose[B](implicitasArray:A=%3EArray[B]):Array[Array[B]]).